# UIScreen.main.bounds.width Is deprecated

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uiscreen

in SwiftUI,my var has UIScreen.main.bounds.width.

**@State private var buttonWidth: Double = UIScreen.main.bounds.width.**

UIScreen.main.bounds.width Is deprecated. (main is deprecated)
how can i solve?

thank you

Comment: running iOS 16?

Comment: Using this metric in SwiftUI is a pretty questionable practice anyway. Are you sure you don't want to use the SwiftUI sizing features (like `frame`) or even `GeometryReader`?

Comment: running from IOS15 +.

Comment: how are the sizing functions (such as the frame) or even GeometryReader managed? unfortunately the documentation is often empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `.frame()` modifier to your button in your view and let it occupy the screen width infinitely

```
var body: some View {
    YourButtonClass()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
```

Here's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/frame(minwidth:idealwidth:maxwidth:minheight:idealheight:maxheight:alignment:)) on the frame modifier

Comment: I wonder why I never thought of that. Thanks!